# Markov Chain recurrent and transients states

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, self-learning, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain on $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ specified by the following transition matrix.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0.2& 0.2 &0.5& 0&0.1\\
0.3 &0& 0.3& 0.4&0\\
0.2 &0.3& 0.2 &0.3&0\\
0& 0& 0& 0.8&0.2\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Am I correct that:

(1) there are three communicating classes: $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4\}$, $\{5\}$.

(2) State 5 is an absorbing state

(3)  $\{4\}$ is transient,

(4) $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{5\}$ are recurrent.

Comment: Yes, everything is fine with your answer.